# More efficient case-insensitive substring search

Tags: ruby, refactoring

Can anyone tell me a more efficient way of doing `url.downcase.include? "some string"` in the following context?

```
def source
  return if url.nil?

  source = nil

  if url.downcase.include? 'techcrunch.com' or url.downcase.include? 'tcrn.ch'
    source = 'techcrunch'
  end

  source
end
```

I'm just starting out with Ruby, so if you have any other tips I'd appreciate them.

Thank you so much,
  Pamela

Comment: Naturally, you should search for 'techcrunch.com` first if you believe it is more likely to be present than 'tcrn.ch'; otherwise, search for 'tcrn.ch' first. As for tips, get used to reading the docs for Ruby methods.  Methods are referred to like this: `klass_name#method_name`.  Here, for example, you are using the method [String#include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant computational efficiency yours is about as good as it gets except perhaps calling `.downcase` twice. But really performance wise you will not get much improvement from anything in such a simple case.

If you are looking for a shorter way to write your implementation, this is probably about as short as possible:

```
def source(url)
  url =~ /techcrunch\.com|tcrn\.ch/i && 'vimeo'
end

source('www.stackoverflow.com') # => nil
source('www.techcrunch.com') # => "vimeo"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def source
  return unless url
  downcased_url = url.downcase
  'vimeo' if %w[techcrunch.com tcrn.ch].any? { |u| downcased_url.include? u }
end
```